# number of sets including the most popular elements in intersecting sets family

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let $F$ be a set consisting of some subsets of $[n]$, and any two sets in $F$ have at least one element in common. I think I read a result stating as following: there exists an element $x$, such that at least half of $F$ include $x$. But I do not remember the related reference. Do anyone know the reference or some similar results?Thanks.

Comment: Frankl union-closed sets conjecture?

Comment: You may be thinking of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union-closed_sets_conjecture

Comment: In view of the given link to the Frankl conjecture and Fedor's answer, it seems that the missing assumption in your statement is that $F$ should be closed under taking unions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is completely false. Consider the lines of a finite projective plane.

Comment: Sorry for not stating the problem clearly. $F$ is consisting of subsets of $[n]$

Comment: So what? Enumerate the points from 1 to $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Is such generality the result is false. If you have $n$ sets, you can always define ${n \choose 2}$ elements such that each of them is contained in a different couple of sets. This way all the sets have non-empty intersection and no element is contained in more than $2$ sets.